# Control a separate process in python using multiprocessing module

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I am wondering what is the easiest way to be able to control a process started by the main function in python.

For example, in  my main loop I call a function that will be a separate process and its only purpose is to collect data to a buffer. Then whenever I want, I will indicate to that process to stop collecting data and to store it in a text file. Then, when it completes writing to file I would like it to wait for another signal (coming from main) before it starts the same loop again, that is, collecting new data to a buffer. The process will repeat indefinitely, though it would be awesome if I had the ability to actually stop the process until I want new data.
I tried using multiprocessing.Event() but for some reason when I event.set() or event.clear() the message sometimes isn't received in time and thus the data formatting is screwed up.

Example:

```
def separateProcess():
    datBuffer = []
    while True:
        datBuffer.append(collectData(sample))
        if signal.recv == 'TimeToWriteToFile':
            #Write the data buffer to file.
            while True:
                if signal.recv == 'NewData':
                    #Signal to begin recording new data has been received
                    datBuffer = [] #clear the buffer for new data.
                    break
        else:
            #Continue recording Data.
            pass

def main():
    #This code will do some stuff regarding the experiment.
    p = mp.Process(target=separateProcess)
    p.start()


    #Based on a particular event I will send the signal when needed.
    if experiment == 'Success':
        sendToProc('TimeToWriteToFile') #Theoretical signal to the other process.
        sleep(10) #Wait for X amount of seconds then begin recording new data.

        sendToProc('NewData')
```

I can provide the code sample of my failed attempt at creating such script if needed. But basically I wish to know a method to achieve what I have up there, it would also be awesome if that method worked using global variables as signals. I know I can't since a new process does not share global state...

That's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks pretty good.  I suggest creating a `Queue` in the parent process, then sending anything to your worker, which will output the data.  When the parent proc wants the worker to die, send a `None`.

### source

```
import multiprocessing, Queue

def myproc(arg):
    return arg*2

def worker(inqueue):
    for num in iter(inqueue.get, None):
        print myproc(num)


inq = multiprocessing.Queue()
# prefill with 3 jobs
for num in range(3):
    inq.put(num)
# signal end of jobs
inq.put(None)

worker_p = multiprocessing.Process(
    target=worker, args=(inq,),
)
worker_p.start()

worker_p.join()
```

### output

```
0
2
4
```

Comment: Thanks!
So if I understand your code correctly, could it be possible to run my worker in a loop that which will continue collecting data until the queue receives a none at which point, would I be able to tell the thread to quickly store the data to a file then wait until it receives a new Queue item which will make it enter the same loop of storing data to a buffer temporarily again?

Comment: Not quite: send anything (ie: `True`) to the worker to get it to do something.  In this case the worker would store the data.  Yes, at that point the worker would continue the loop, waiting for another `True`.  For the parent to ask the worker to exit, send it a `None`.